# Change bitmap position continuously in canvas with invalidate shows different behaviours on different resolution screen

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, screen-resolution, ondraw

I am developing a game, i am incrementing the position of bitmap on canvas using invalidate, so now it is like moving the image on screen, i have incrementing the position by 1, so the value of (x,y) of bitmap is changing.
My problem is incrementing the position over canvas by value 1 shows very slow in higher resolution and its good in ldpi and mdpi devices. I couldn't find the actual problem..
wether the problem is density or frame per second or some thing.Help me.

Comment: if ypu want a constant speed (velocity) this is how you do it: v = s / t

Comment: hi, how could i get s? Is this the screen width(resolution in x term) or something else..??

Comment: s is displacement in whatever units you need, pixels, inches etc

Comment: No, if i am using screen resolution to get s it will show very slow in high resolution and good in low,i.e. very slow in MOTO G and fast in SAMSUNG NOTE 2.And both have same resolution

Comment: so changing the equation: s = v * t, it seems you are not talking "t" into account

Comment: i am doing increment in onDraw() method. onDraw calls itself continously using invalidate method.. so i dont think t has a role in this calculation.. is this thing depend on frame per second of onDraw() method or canvas or something else, that may be reson incremeting the pixel value by 1 is slow or fast which differ in devices

Comment: again: ds = v * dt,  try to Log.d the value of dt

Comment: My question is incrementing the x coordinate inside onDraw() method of canvas is not showing me correct behavior in all devices. speed is not same in all devices although i am incrementing the x value by same factor(say something 1)..

Comment: i give up,  seems you are not listening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the same speed in all devices then you need to multiply the increment value with `density`. Let's say your increment value is `1px` then you need to use

```
1 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

This will make sure that in higher density devices the increment value is more to keep the speed same.(for ex, in `hdpi` it will be `1.5`, in `xhdpi` it will be `2.0` etc). Hope it helps!

Comment: @user3732498 please accept the answer if it has helped you:)